# Best practice for repurposing a Windows 10 laptop for a charity

Tags: windows-10, formatting

I have several laptops with Windows 10 installed which are BitLocker-encrypted. I am going to gift them to a charity and wondered if it was sufficient to use the in-built "Reset this PC" option.

Ideally, the "reset" will remove the BitLocker key, and it should not persist after the OS is reinstalled via the "reset this PC" option.

Can anybody share insight into the process? If the BitLocker key is removed, and OS re-installed, then I guess it is safe and not necessary to perform a low-level format using a tool like Active@ Kill Disk.

Comment: If you go into the BIOS and clear the TPM then the disk encryption key will be destroyed. In order to recover the encrypted data the person would need access to your recovery key stored in the microsoft account. Lacking either of those keys you can simply reinstall the system using any media which will repartition the disk and wipe all partitions. https://williamhartz.medium.com/how-to-reset-a-laptop-without-bitlocker-recovery-key-69a4d12b5f2d

Comment: Don't over think the process.  Without the encryption key, it will be impossible, to recover deleted encrypted data.  So all you have to do is, delete the partitions, and then reinstall Windows.  Just stop short of creating an account.